# Python:delete number in list

Tags: python

I just learn python.I have a problem here.It is simple code,But I don't know why the result is unexpected.

here is my code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,6,7,'dd','ss','gg','oo',8]

for i in a:
    for b in range(10):
        if i==b:
            a.remove(i)

print a
```

I want to delete the number in a. I am expecting the result will be a=['dd','ss','gg','00']
but the result is :

```
[2, 4, 7, 'dd', 'ss', 'gg', 'oo']
```

I cannot understand why the result is this.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Never iterate through a list and delete from it. Instead make a new list and add everything you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this remove all integer from list

```
      a = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, int)]
```

Comment: can you tell me why the result is strange?